# OSRM. How I can to get route (points array) between my points

Tags: javascript, osrm

I have two points and I want to get a route with roads. In documentation I read I should to send this request:

```
http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/{first_point},{last_point}?overview=false
```

[image]

I waiting to see many points in 'waypoints', but I see only two points near by my points.

[image]

Where are I can to get my points array with all roads and crossroads?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the steps=true parameter to get your list of "legs" containing all waypoints in between your starting- and endpoint.